# Need to Create vertical after horizontal and then after again vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have to create scrolling effect same as below demo with vanilla javascript without any jQuery plugin.
https://www.ls.graphics/dsk This is demo URL where this functionality already has done. I am talking about this section http://prntscr.com/o48jcb which is the third section from the top.

I have tried this but here I was able to make horizontal scroll but can't make a vertical scroll.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.hScroll = function (amount) {
        amount = amount || 120;
        $(this).bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel", function (event) {
            var oEvent = event.originalEvent, 
                direction = oEvent.detail ? oEvent.detail * -amount : oEvent.wheelDelta, 
                position = $(this).scrollLeft();
            position += direction > 0 ? -amount : amount;
            $(this).scrollLeft(position);
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').hScroll(60); // You can pass (optionally) scrolling amount
});
```

```css
#box {
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
.item {
    display: flex;
    
    min-width: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 140px;
    border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: 1.6;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">2</div>
 <div class="item">3</div>
 <div class="item">4</div>
 <div class="item">5</div>
 <div class="item">6</div>
 <div class="item">7</div>
 <div class="item">8</div>
 <div class="item">9</div>
<div id="box">
    <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
   <div class="item">6</div>
   <div class="item">7</div>
   <div class="item">8</div>
   <div class="item">9</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">2</div>
 <div class="item">3</div>
 <div class="item">4</div>
 <div class="item">5</div>
 <div class="item">6</div>
 <div class="item">7</div>
 <div class="item">8</div>
 <div class="item">9</div>
 <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">2</div>
 <div class="item">3</div>
 <div class="item">4</div>
 <div class="item">5</div>
 <div class="item">6</div>
 <div class="item">7</div>
 <div class="item">8</div>
 <div class="item">9</div>
 <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">2</div>
 <div class="item">3</div>
 <div class="item">4</div>
 <div class="item">5</div>
 <div class="item">6</div>
 <div class="item">7</div>
 <div class="item">8</div>
 <div class="item">9</div>
```

Here I am able to create horizontal scrolling but at a time can't able to make vertical scrolling.

I need the same functionality as the above site has already done like vertical scrolling and then horizontal scroll after that again vertical scroll with vanilla javascript without any jQuery plugin.

Comment: _“I need the same functionality”_ - well then – start coding it. // Please go read [ask]. This is not a site to get code written for you, and neither to ask for external resources such as tutorials etc. We are here to answer specific questions about specific problems with code you have written. You can come back once you have something to show in those regards.

Comment: @04FS Can you please see below code.